# Can I stop Scavenging without being attacked?

Tags: organ-trail

I've just started playing *Organ Trail: Director's Cut* on Steam, and I can't figure out if there's a way to voluntarily stop scavenging. I've tried to walk off of the screen, but that doesn't seem to work, though I've only been able to try at the top and the left side. I don't want to keep burning through my medkits though.

Is there a button to do this? Do you need to just scavenge for a certain amount of time? Or do you indeed have to wait until you get attacked?

Comment: Judging by the comments on @BlueRaja's answer, you may want to include your system.

Answer (score 2):

You have to keep scavenging until you've picked up three things.

Until then, your only choices are to get yourself killed, or run in circles like a madman until more items appear.

[image: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH]

Comment: its not an item limit but time limit.  There were scavenges where I've picked up way more than 3 things but it didn't end until a certain time.  And there were also scavenges where I couldn't pick up anything due to zombie position and item placement, which stinks but its better to run out the time than to be bitten.

Comment: @spartacus: I've had scavenges last a few seconds because all three items appeared at the start, and I've had a scavenge last well over 5 minutes because the third item refused to appear.  *(Edit: I play on Steam)*

Comment: hrmm... never happened to me, I wonder if its version differences?  I play on android.

Comment: I can verify the time limit on Android.  I've not played it on Steam though.

Comment: @BlueRaja So... I'm really confused now. I'm also playing on Steam, but it seems that I have the same thing as spartacus, a time limitation (I finally somewhat stopped being awful at scavenging). I have the Director's Cut, do you? That's the only reason I can think that it'd be different.